# Create animated chart of a dataset with multiples columns by year

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

the dataset is

| year | ID | top_1 | top_2 | top_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1952 | 25 | 7012 | 6647 | 6419 |
| 1953 | 28 | 8850 | 7165 | 6470 |
| 1954 | 31 | 8188 | 7678 | 7246 |
| 1955 | 34 | 8586 | 8485 | 7525 |
| 1956 | 37 | 8850 | 8516 | 8163 |
| 1957 | 40 | 7525 | 6501 | NA |
| 1958 | 43 | 8188 | 6165 | NA |
| 1959 | 46 | 6707 | 6187 | 5630 |

I want to get something like this
[image: year wise chart]

I am not sure what to put in `aes()` argument

```
p <- ggplot( data = x , aes(year, y = ??  ) +
  geom_bar( stat = "identity" ) +
  transition_states(year) +
  labs(title = "abc") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(5500 , 9000)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("hgt")
animate(p, nframes = 450, fps=16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to reshape your data using `melt`. After that, you can set `transition_states` to show different years of the barplot. To show the year in the title you can use `{next_state}`. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(reshape)

df_melted <- melt(df, id = c("ID", "year"))

p <- df_melted %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity" ) +
  transition_states(
    year,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out') +
  labs(title = "Heighest 3 peaks in Year: {next_state}") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("hgt")
p
```

Output:

[image]